# Access the HTML page inside service in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, jspdf

I want to access particular HTML page inside a service. Currently, I have made the function inside a controller that can be called from its linked HTML page but I want to access that function from multiple pages. So, I'll want service or factory for it to make it available from anywhere.

In that function, I want the content of particular HTML page but that content is available only when I call the function from that page only.

Here is my function.

```
$scope.downloadReport = function(type) {

      var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4');
      var source;

      var options = {
         pagesplit: true,
         background: '#ffffff',
         letterRendering: true
      };
      pdf.internal.scaleFactor = 2;

      source = document.getElementsByClassName('complete-report')[0];

      pdf.addHTML(source, options, function () {
        pdf.save('report.pdf');
      });
  };
```

> *document.getElementsByClassName('complete-report')[0];* It will get data from the HTML page linked with controller.

**So, I need service which access the particular HTML page such that I use that function there to get the content of particular HTML page.**

Comment: Why do you want to get access to HTML in service? You should just pass `source` variable as a parameter to service's method. Service shouldn't be aware how your HTML looks.

Comment: Because I want to download the report from multiple pages and get the content of "particular page". When I called function from other pages, it is taking 'document' of that page only not the "particular page".

Answer (score 0):

As pointed to [wprzechodzen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4130492/wprzechodzen), you shouldn't access directly your HTML inside a service but, instead, you should pass only `source` variable.

However, if you want to access HTML in service you have to do something like this:

```
yourApp.controller('something', function($scope, $window, $document, yourServiceName){
  yourServiceName.yourFunction($document)
})

yourApp.factory('yourServiceName', function(){
  return {
    yourFunction: function(doc){
       //here you get  $document
    }
  }
})
```

[Here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$document)'s the `$document`'s docs

Comment: The $document will be that 'content' from where I have called the function but not the particular page function. I want every time the $document of the 'particular page'.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure that the DOM element which you are trying to access must be loaded in the DOM. Till then you cant do anything.

You can try giving id tag (e.g. elementID)for that perticular dom element and try accessing like below.

```
var source = angular.element("#elementID");
```

Comment: I have tried it earlier but I don't get the particular #elementID when I call the function from other HTML pages, at that time I get the source of that HTML page from where I have called the function.